# Why does "Docker startup options" of the ShinyProxy "Getting Started" manual state 127.0.0.1:2375?

Tags: docker, shinyproxy

The [Getting started](https://www.shinyproxy.io/documentation/getting-started/) page of [ShinyProxy](https://www.shinyproxy.io/) states to do the following. I will reproduce this so we're all on the same page.

**---------- start reproduction ----------**

```bash
sudo systemctl edit docker
```

This command opens your default editor, add the following content to the file:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H unix:// -D -H tcp://127.0.0.1:2375
```

Next, save the file, close the editor and restart Docker using:

```bash
sudo systemctl restart docker
```

**---------- end reproduction ----------**

If I perform these steps and set `url: http://localhost:2375` in the application.yml my shiny app containers fail to start.

`docker logs` return errors such as:

- `Container with index 0 failed to start`
- `Docker container failed to start`
- `Connect to localhost:2375 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)`

However, if I set both `url: http://172.17.0.1:2375` in the application.yml and `ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H unix:// -D -H tcp://172.17.0.1:2375` in "Docker startup options" it works. `172.17.0.1` is the `IPv4 address for docker0` on my host system. The application.yml also defines `internal-networking: true`.

I am running shinyproxy `3.0.2` via its docker image ( `openanalytics/shinyproxy:3.0.2`).

Can someone explain this?

Comment: Standard disclaimer: that's horrible advice in a getting started guide. The recommendation creates a local root escalation vulnerability to any user or process that can access that well known port. All it takes to pop a root shell is `docker run -it --rm --privileged --pid host debian nsenter -t 1 -m -u -n -i bash`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the key to the described behaviour is that ShinyProxy is being run via docker container (`openanalytics/shinyproxy:3.0.2`), which will "simply" not allow networking via `localhost/127.0.0.1`.

Presumably networking should run in a docker specific manner e.g. via `172.17.0.1:2375` or `docker.sock`.

My conclusion is that the "Getting started" page is a description if you want to run the standalone java application and not its dockerized version.

FWIW:
I've now switched to the following `docker` settings in the application.yaml, which also do not require the docker startup options to be edited. Setting `url` seems not to be strictly needed if setting `internal-networking: true`.

```yaml
docker:
    internal-networking: true
    url: unix:///var/run/docker.sock
```